# Move files and create folders script on windows?

Tags: windows-7, batch, script, batch-file, file-organization

Here's the situation: I have about 200k images on a folders (they're divided into thousands of subfolders). What i want to do:

1. Create a undefined amount of subfolders in another folder
2. move 500 files into each folder to make easier to sort the images each day

Is there a automated way of doing this? Maybe a batch script or software? I'm sorry but i know little of programming.

Comment: Iterate the files in a folder with a `for` and count, calculate with `set /a "count+=1,extent=count / 500"`

Comment: Gyugas - Clarify a bit on your folder structure you are starting with some. You have `/ParentFolder` then you have beneath it `/ChildFolderA`, `/ChildFolderB` and so on? You want something that will go in `/ChildA` first, get 500 files and then move to some other folder where exactly? How to know which files go to which of the new destination folders? Do files of 500 chunk groups copied over need to occur from chronologically sorted folders and files based on folder and file name or just dump 500 randomly from any combination to any of the new folders or what?